# What is the profile of gradutes from University of Louisville, College of Arts and Sciences and Dept of Biology?

Tags: education, collegescorecard

I have looked at the following webpage: College Scorecard

https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/school/?157289-University-of-Louisville

and obtained some University-wide data, but am looking for program-specific data. For University of Louisville overall, could you provide a more detailed undergraduate student profile (for example 1) Demographic data, but also 2) Income data, 3) First time college student data). Secondly, is it possible to get that information for the College of Arts and Sciences and  also the Dept of Biology (both BA and BS programs combined is fine)?

Comment: Since you want specific data from one particular department at one particular school, I think the best chance would be to contact that department.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, Scorecard does not provide those data at the program-level.  Please note planned changes in IPEDS and NSLDS reporting may allow program-level data to be reported in the future.

Comment: planned changes...may allow - so, please note that we may or may not have it in the future? appreciate the answer and information, but don't see how that's informative/helpful/constructive. wondering if i'm missing something; perhaps i'm looking into it to much...

Comment: albert, I think it's helpful in the sense that it says "No, we don't have it now, but we may in the future." In other words, it indicates "This is a feature request, not a bug report," but doesn't guarantee the feature will be available.

Comment: Thanks, Evan.  Indeed Scorecard does not currently provide earnings by major/program of study. Earnings data are collected by matching student grant and loan data to tax records and student grant/loan records did not have this level of detail until 2012. The 2012 entry cohort would be the first possible cohort to examine earnings by major/program with this methodology (As such, 2022 would be the first available 10-year post-entry earnings calculation opportunity).